# importing class in microservice 1 from another microservice 2

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, entitymanagerfactory

I have two micro-services, I use Spring Boot: Parametrization and Patient
I have an entity bed in a mc parametrization I want to import the entity patient in the mc Patient that's generating a problem when I run the mc parametrization :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Patient
```

I try to import class patient (mc2) to class bed (mc1) : springboot